# Chapter-section-theorem numbering

Tags: numbering

I have two independent chapters. I want to override the chapter numbering. So for example, a theorem 7 in section 3 in chapter 2 is labeled as 2.3.7. How could I get only the label 3.7?.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the recursive section numbering (that is, `\thesection`) from `\thetheorem` by adding

```
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theorem}}
```

to your preamble.

Unless stated otherwise, this will still leave sections to be reset with every new chapter. As such, you might end up with two theorems numbered 3.7, say.